# How to reload Form A from Form B (which was originally called from Form A)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I can't figure this out .. please help if you would be so kind.  I have a form named frmMain and from it I call a form named frmSettings.  On the frmSettings form I have SAVE button that essentially saves the contents of frmSettings to a XML file and close the frmSettings form ... and then displays frmMain again.  The problem is that frmMain is not updated with the contents of frmSettings or the updated XML file.  So I essentially want to reload frmMain, but Call frmMain_Load() is not available as an option.   How do I reload frmMain after saving and closing frmSettings?

Answer (score 1):

one way to do that is: moving  the code  that  loads the xml from the  load method to separated PUBLIC sub,

```
public Sub LoadXML()
        'xml code  here
 End Sub
```

then,  when you  update the xml file you just need yo call `frmMain.LoadXML()`

remeber to call  LoadXML on `frmMain_Load()`

Comment: My XML is loaded in my frmMain_Load event which also populates to the textboxes on the frmMain.  I tried copying the code from the frmMain_Load event to a new sub "frmMain_Reload" already, but that didn't work either.   Now when I try to load the frmSettings I get a runtime error: System.ArgumentException: 'This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property.
Parameter name: binding'

Here's the pseudo code for frmMain_Load or frmMain_Reload events
- Clone the Settings dt
- Readxml into dt clone
- Populate frmMain txtBoxes with contents of dt clone

Comment: I was able to resolve my problem by doing what @MorenajeRD suggested. I created a frmMain_Reload event (that mimics frmMain_Load) but at the top of it I clear out all of the object data bindings one by one.

Comment: nice to hear that you solved it,  don't think about your question being close,  sometimes weird things happen .